# JSON python

Tags: python, json

С интересной проблемой столкнулся, есть json в котором массив, внутри массива вложены объекты, например:

```
[
  {
        "test": true,
        "netest": false,
        "numder": 0,
        "string": "Hello"
    }, {
        "test": true,
        "netest": false,
        "numder": 1,
        "string": "Hello"
    }, {
        "test": true,
        "netest": false,
        "numder": 2,
        "string": "Hello"
    }
]
```

сам код

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json

s = '[{"test":true, "netest":false, "numder":0, "string":"Hello"},{"test":true, "netest":false, "numder":1, "string":"Hello"},{"test":true, "netest":false, "numder":2, "string":"Hello"}]'

a = json.dumps(s)
b = json.loads(a)
print a
print s[0]
```

Суть такова, json не пребразуется в массив, а получаеться строка, как быть в такой ситуации. 
З.Ы. с json в питоне впервые работаю, посему могу некоторых тонкостей не знать, если не трудно покажите на пальцах в чем косяк.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кажется, вы перепутали `json.dumps` и `json.loads` местами – первый сериализует, а второй десериализует. Соответственно, вы просто пытаетесь сериализовать объект-строку, а не загрузить сериализованный массив.

Comment: Оно)) Спасибо, под вечер туплю, да и с английским плоховато.